# AngularJS : dialog as ng view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assuming we have a single page with full screen background and couple of links on the top of the page. 
I know how to load partial html pages in a container using angularjs and routing configuration but now the scenario is a bit different.
I'm looking for a way that each time user clicks on the application'link load the content in the modal dialog.User able to close the dialog but if user clicks link or changes routing the appropriate content to be load and show in the dialog.
My point is not just showing the dialog using angular.For example I want to if user changes the route to www.sitename.com/#about web-application loads about in the dialog and show it.
Is it possible?

Comment: using bootstrap? https://github.com/Fundoo-Solutions/angularjs-modal-service or http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ under model

Comment: @wayne Thank you, Bootstrap is good option. But does dialog service able me to load the content into dialog ? My point is not just showing the dialog using angular.For example I want if user changes the route to www.sitename.com/#about web-application loads about in the dialog and show it.